# Azure "Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect or have expired"

Tags: azure, computer-vision

I have a token with computer vision included in the scope and audience. But when a send an OCR request it always returns "Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect or have expired". What is wrong with my code?

curl --location --request POST 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.0/ocr' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer myToken' 
--data-raw '{"url":"imageUrl"}'

Comment: Could you pls share that how you get this token ?

Comment: You mean that the problem is with the token? If yes, I do not think so because when I convert it to human readable text with www.jwt.io, it contains the vision api in the scope and audience

Comment: Hi Zyad, I think this issue has been solved in my previous post, would you allow me to summarize an answer, and please kindly accept it to close this question?

Comment: Yes for sure Mr. Stanley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls just try the request below to get an access token from Azure AD for the vision OCR service:

[image]